# android webview causing null pointer

Tags: java, android, webview, nullpointerexception

I have this in my layout :

```
<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

This in my activity:

```
public class Shop extends Activity {
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView webview;
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.example.co.uk/shop");
}
}
```

and this in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Yet when i run the application, i get a force close error and something about a null pointer in the log.. I've never used webview before so have no idea what i'm doing!

Comment: please add logcat message to your question

Comment: com.example.chobbyblings.Shop.onCreate(Shop.java:15) -error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);`:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

Comment: That was so obvious.. thank you! Sorry I probably should've known that!